# Overlay div on fixed body fails fixed pos when window resized

Tags: css

To sum it up:

On deploy popup overlay:

1. Add overflow:hidden to `<body>`
2. Append .floater div with `css: overflow-y:scroll; position:fixed; top/left/right/bottom:0; z-index:1000`
3. Append .overlay div within `.floater with css: pos:rel, width:600px; height:800px; background:#fff; margin:40px auto;`

As expected, when trying to scroll, scroll only applies to the .overlay correctly.

**However, after resizing the window by any moment, the scroll now applies to both body and .overlay div.**

Example posted @ http://mkn.us/test.php

*The issue seems to only occur on Google Chrome + I'm on a mac scrolling via touch pad / mac mouse.*

Comment: Please provide us with some code and perhaps an example

Comment: @Zeaklous see http://mkn.us/test.php

Comment: It doesn't seem to happen on Chrome Windows.

Comment: It seems this is only a Chrome Mac issue.  I'm moving it to Google Chrome bugs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue was a Chrome Bug and is now solved with the latest Chrome version: 30.0.1599.66

Comment: I'm still experiencing this on 32.0.1700.76 beta, any idea?

Comment: @omerc.net you're right, this issue is back.  Reactivating the bug @ chrome.